# How to access qr code via web page opened in offline mode

Tags: html, iphone, webcam

So what I want to do:

Open html file offline -> Open QR Code functionality -> Get Access to device camera -> take a QR code picture -> obtain and use those data as I wish.

What is the problem:

Since I am trying to get access into device camera from offline web page there is a need for HTTPS connection.

Question:

Is there a way how to obtain those data from mobile devices (for example) without the need for local https server?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. I have had good experience with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/library